# Is there an operator than I can use to "dispose" a resource allocated in a pipeline?

Tags: rxjs, reactivex

Say I have an observable:

```js
declare function allocateLeakyThing(input: string): { dispose: () => void; };

const somethingLeaky$ = input$.pipe(
  map(allocateLeakyThing)
);
```

where `allocateLeakyThing()` returns a resource that has to be manually disposed by calling its `dispose()` method in order to prevent memory leak. If `input$` emits a new value, I should dispose the previously allocated resource; if this observable is unsubscribed, it should dispose the resource too, if it's ever allocated.

For the first purpose I can write:

```js
const somethingLeaky$ = input$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(somethingLeaky$.pipe(startsWith(undefined))),
  tap(([input, somethingLeaky]) => somethingLeaky?.dispose()),
  map(([input])=>allocateLeakyThing(input))
);
```

What about the second purpose? Is there a way to do this inline with this observable (e.g. does not involve using another subject)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `finalize()` operator that is called when a chain is being disposed (unsubscribed).

Since RxJS 7.3. you can also use `tap({ finalize: () => {} })`.

Maybe in your situation you could also wrap the logic that creates the ressurce with `Observable` (basically the same thing as in [Is there a way to make a destructor for RXJS Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72388150/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-destructor-for-rxjs-observables)):

```
new Observable(observer => {
  // create resource
  // ...

  // Return teardown function that will be called when the Observable is unsubscribed.
  return () => resource.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The `new Observable(...` approach looks very promising.